# Flask: How to prevent Google Analytics JS to run in dev environment?

Tags: google-analytics, flask

When signing up with google analytics there is a piece of js script that needs to be inserted in the `base.html`

```
<script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'xxx', 'example.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

Problem with having it always there is, that development machines would submit unnecessary data that is not from real users.  I was wondering if there is a way to ask if flask is in the debug mode, and hence do not load this script in first place.

How can I check for debug mode in the template?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not using it already you should create one file called `config.py` and then load it into your Flask app, by doing something like this:

```
import config
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(config)
```

Then in the `config.py` file you can write:

```
# Running on App Enginge
PRODUCTION = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine') 
# Running Localy
DEVELOPMENT = not PRODUCTION
# You decide when is DEBUG mode, usually when running locally
DEBUG = DEVELOPMENT
```

And then in your template you can use these values like this:

```
{% if not config.DEBUG %}
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

You could also exclude the admin users of your application to affect the analytics since they are most likely going to abuse them anyway. If you implemented the `current_user` the Flask way then your template should be change to:

```
{% if not current_user.admin and not config.DEBUG %}
  <script>
    ...
  </script>
{% endif %}
```

Among other things, all of the above ([config.py](https://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init/src/tip/main/config.py), [main.py](https://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init/src/tip/main/main.py), [analytics.html](https://bitbucket.org/lipis/gae-init/src/tip/main/templates/bit/analytics.html)) above are used in my [gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com) project.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but i think the templates have access to config object. So you can try something like:

```
{% if not config['DEBUG'] %}
    <script> .... </script>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case with my Flask site. I want to log activity for my users, but I do not want my own activity as admin to go to Analytics and skew the stats.

I have added a `g.is_admin` to my `before_request` handler:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.admin = current_user.is_admin()
```

Then in the template I skip the Analytics code when appropriate using a conditional:

```
{% if not g.admin %}
    <script> ... </script>
{% endif %}
```

Depending on how your environment is set up you will need to come up with a condition that can differentiate the development vs production machines. This could be as simple as a configuration item, or check if debug mode is on.

Comment: This is still not really ok since you might want to test a normal user or not logged in users locally without sending anything to analytics..

Comment: As I said above, you have to find the correct condition that you can use to tell a development machine apart from a production machine. For me it was about admin vs. not admin, for you it could be a matter of checking the hostname of the machine, the IP address, something that uniquely identifies your development machines.